# how to remove the service, time and charging indications at the top of iOs7 device

Tags: xcode, ios6, cordova, ios7, mgwt

I built an app using MGWT and GwtPhonegap which is running good in ios6. I updated my Xcode to make it compatible to ios7. And I also updated my iPhone OS from 6 to ios7. I installed the same app through the updated Xcode into my device. In each screen of my app,the device showing
service indication(left), time (center) and charging indication(right). Is there any possibility
to remove these with the Xcode configuration or is there any other approach to do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your project's config.xml there is a preference called "fullscreen". Set it to "true".

(assuming you're using Phonegap 3+)

In older versions: add a key called UIStatusBarHidden to your [appname]-info.plist and set it to true. In raw XML that would be

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true />
```

Comment: I'm using GwtPhonegap 2.0

Comment: I've no idea what Gwt is, but I've updated my answer for older versions of Phonegap.